# Is there any faster way than .Any() to find if IEnumerable<T> has any data?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, ienumerable

When running the profiler on my code I am showing a total execution time of 20 seconds, 14 seconds of this (14,788.4 ms) is being taken up by a call to IEnumerable.Any() is there any way to speed this up at all?

The table being pulled from has a total of ~484,000 records, so putting that in to memory would be best avoided.

I have tried Replacing IEnumerable.Any() with IEnumerable.Count() > 0 and using IEnumerable.GetEnumerator().MoveNext()

All of which provide no significant change in execution time.

```
IEnumerable<Registration> result = [Fill by Query] (19ms)
[Conditions] (<0.1ms for all)
[Tried all of the following with no performance impact]
return result != null && result.Any(); (14000ms)
return result != null && result.Count() > 0; (14000ms)
return result != null && result.GetEnumerator().MoveNext(); (14000ms)
return (result?.Any() ?? false); (14000ms)
```

I'm hoping that I can find something that will reduce the total execution time to a reasonable number, IEnumerable.Any() being the only bottleneck.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to call `Queryable.Any`, not `Enumerable.Any`, so that the actual database query can be adjusted to only query whether or not any items exist.  By turning the `IQueryable` into an `IEnumerable` you're ensuring that the operations you're performing on it all involve materializing the results of the query in memory before that operation can be performed.

Comment: I could actually kiss you right now, that small change made the .Any() execution time go from 14,788.4ms to 312.4ms